# Move Complete ORACLE from one system to another

Tags: centos, database

[image]

I have 2 identical server with exact disk partitions (OS CENTOS 6.4 both ) [My college central oracle server].

Entire ORACLE HOME ( bin , control files, data files everything on oracle) is on 2nd Disk (which is not a OS disk)

Since OLD server had reached end of life (from HP) a new HP machine with upgraded RAM (OLD system had 16 GIG where as new system as 64 GIG).

Now Since All oracle Dependencies (RPM, libraries, environmental variables, JAVA, Users and groups) are already made on new server.

So Now Question is ..

Can I remove Disk [Oracle HDD] from OLD server and insert it on NEW server and just start Oracle (sqlplus "/ as sysdba" or dbstart and lnsctrl).

Can it will give any challenge.
(I have cold backups, export backup, & RMAN backup too).

I just want to give a try on above case.

Will this work ??

Comment: Oracle is quite resilient, so there are good chances it goes smoothly. Just be sure that **EVERYTHING** is in-sync in your `ora.ini` (or whatever ini file your Oracle instance is using).

Comment: Yess.. Actually I did earlier migration with control files , datafiles and archieve and redo logs with sp and pfile same.. but since here entire oracle resides on separate disk, this time I am thinking of giving a shot of moving full oracle (ofcourse backups first) (Complete shift of disks)(there will be no oracle installation in 2nd server)

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. But as Oracle install is quite self-sufficient, the only thing you should worry are the pre-requisites (you already checked the libs): kernel (shared mem), users and libs

Comment: Yess.. RPMs, users, Groups, limits.conf, sysctl.conf, libraries.. everything is same

Comment: Can you provide information on the specific models of the servers you're working with?